# Can't find missing matching rows in SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Quite new to SQL so please be patient. 
I have two tables, one is a `Locations` table and one is a `FileImport` table. 
I get files daily and I then import them they then get sorted based on the **Locations** in the `Locations` table. 
My usual method of tracking the missed ones are done via Excel but there must be a simpler way through SQL.
 I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT dbo.Location.LocationDesc, 
       dbo.FileImport.LocationName, 
       dbo.FileImport.CreatedDate, 
       dbo.FileImport.FileName
FROM dbo.FileImport left OUTER JOIN dbo.Location 
      ON dbo.FileImport.LocationName = dbo.Location.LocationDesc
where CAST(dbo.FileImport.CreatedDate AS Date) = '2016-09-14'
```

There are some older **Locations** that are not used within the Locations table but for now I want to find all **Locations** in the `Locations` table which don't have a corresponding upload for that day, any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: you probably want to use NOT EXISTS e.g SELECT dbo.Location.LocationDesc FROM dbo.Location WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.FileImport WHERE dbo.FileImport.LocationName = dbo.Location.LocationDesc AND CAST(dbo.FileImport.CreatedDate AS Date) = '2016-09-14')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll give you all locations that dont have an file import on 14-Sep-2016

```
SELECT loc.LocationDesc
FROM
dbo.Location loc
where not exists 
(select null from 
dbo.FileImport fi
where fi.LocationName = loc.LocationDesc
and CAST(dbo.FileImport.CreatedDate AS Date) = '2016-09-14');
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I want! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dbo.Location.LocationDesc, dbo.FileImport.LocationName, dbo.FileImport.CreatedDate, dbo.FileImport.FileName

FROM         dbo.Location

left OUTER JOIN   dbo.FileImport   ON dbo.FileImport.LocationName = dbo.Location.LocationDesc
                     and CAST(dbo.FileImport.CreatedDate AS Date) = '2016-09-14'

where   dbo.FileImport.LocationName is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT L.LocationDesc
    ,FI.LocationName
    ,FI.CreatedDate
    ,FI.FileName
FROM dbo.FileImport FI
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Location L ON FI.LocationName = L.LocationDesc
    AND CAST(FI.CreatedDate AS DATE) = '2016-09-14'
WHERE L.LocationDesc IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query. It results locations present in dump but not in *dbo.Location* table.

```
SELECT  fi.LocationName, fi.LocationName, fi.CreatedDate, fi.FileName
FROM    dbo.FileImport AS fi
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Location AS l WHERE fi.LocationName = l.LocationDesc
                      AND CAST(fi.CreatedDate AS Date) = '2016-09-14'
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query,

```
SELECT L.LocationDesc
    ,FI.LocationName
    ,FI.CreatedDate
    ,FI.FileName
FROM dbo.FileImport FI
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Location L ON FI.LocationName = L.LocationDesc
    AND CAST(FI.CreatedDate AS DATE) = '2016-09-14'
WHERE FI.LocationDesc IS NULL
```